# how to pass a single variable to html from php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

i just want to know how to send a variable from the php page to html page ?

this is my user_check.php code :

```
<? php
$var="1021";
?>
```

and my user.html code is

```
<div id="var" type="hidden"/>
```

i just want to pass the variable $var to the div control and need to store the variable in value attribute of div . i searched all the google but no solutions available . can anyone help ? 
Thank you

Comment: Echo it. And why do you want to hide it?

Comment: do you want feature like `mvc` ??

Comment: i want  to show it to another php page not in the same html

Comment: yes MVC @ShowStopper

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ajax` to get the data like this . use this function in you `user.html`

```
<div id="var" type="hidden"/>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'user_check.php',   // link your page
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                //'key1': data1,
                // 'key2': data2
                //if you want to post somethig 
            },
            success: function(data) {
               // got success data
               $('#var').html(data);   // set value in the div
            },
            error: function(data) {
               // if error occure
                alert('Some Error Occurred. Please Try Later.');
            }
        });
});
```

in your `user_check.php` echo what you want to show . as ajax will display the data which will print

```
<? php
echo $var="1021";
?>
```

> **Note** you may need to include jquery library for this

if jquery is not present . include this cdn

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if you want to know more about how `.ajax` work follow this [refrence](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [refrence2](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

**update**

Another way to do this is `include` user.html after variable declaration .then `user_check.php` will

```
<?php
$var="1021";
include('user.html');
?>
```

and user.html will

```
<div id="var" type="hidden"><?php echo $var; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for something like this:

```
<? php
$var="1021";
?> 

<input id="var" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $var; ?>"/>
```

You can then access the value in Javascript.  For example, using jQuery:

```
$('#var').val();
```

Comment: how this will work ??can you explain ?  both pages are different . one is `user_check.php`  other is `user.html`

Comment: My mistake.  You'd have to either to an ajax request or store the answer in localStorage.